# Using S3 data in a Spark Application

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am new to the spark and have some fundamental doubts. I am working on a pyspark application. It is supposed to process 500K items. The current implementation is not efficient and takes forever to complete. 
I will briefly explain the tasks.

The application processes a S3 directory. It is supposed to process all the files present under `s3://some-bucket/input-data/`. The S3 directory structure looks like the below:

```
s3://some-bucket/input-data/item/Q12/sales.csv
s3://some-bucket/input-data/item/Q13/sales.csv
s3://some-bucket/input-data/item/Q14/sales.csv
```

The csv files don't have a item identifier column. The name of directory is the item identifier, like `Q11`, `Q12` etc.

The application has a `udf` defined which downloads the data using boto3, process it, and then dumps the data in S3 in the directory structure like this:

```
s3://some-bucket/output-data/item/Q12/profit.csv
s3://some-bucket/output-data/item/Q13/profit.csv
s3://some-bucket/output-data/item/Q14/profit.csv
```

Making 500K API call to S3 for the data, doesn't seem right to me. I am running the spark application on EMR, should I download all the data as a bootstrap step?

Can [S3DistCp (s3-dist-cp)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html) solve the issue by downloading the whole data to HDFS and later workers/nodes can access them. Suggestions on how to use `s3-dist-cp` would be very helpful.

Comment: To clarify, do you have 500k different objects in S3 or 500k CSV entries in total (in a few S3 objects)?

Comment: 500k different objects in S3. Each item has its own single input file.